# How to use from_json with Kafka connect 0.10 and Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, spark-structured-streaming

I was trying to reproduce the example from [Databricks][1] and apply it to the new connector to Kafka and spark structured streaming however I cannot parse the JSON correctly using the out-of-the-box methods in Spark...

note: the topic is written into Kafka in JSON format.

```
val ds1 = spark
          .readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", IP + ":9092")
          .option("zookeeper.connect", IP + ":2181")
          .option("subscribe", TOPIC)
          .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
          .option("max.poll.records", 10)
          .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
          .load()
```

The following code won't work, I believe that's because the column json is a string and does not match the method from_json signature...

```
    val df = ds1.select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
                .select(from_json("json") as "data")
                .select("data.*")
```

Any tips?

[UPDATE] Example working: 
https://github.com/katsou55/kafka-spark-structured-streaming-example/blob/master/src/main/scala-2.11/Main.scala

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First you need to define the schema for your JSON message. For example

```
val schema = new StructType()
  .add($"id".string)
  .add($"name".string)
```

Now you can use this schema in `from_json` method like below.

```
val df = ds1.select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
            .select(from_json($"json", schema) as "data")
            .select("data.*")
```

Comment: if you have compiler warning "value $ is not a member..." Please don't forget about import spark.implicits._ It took me additional 5-10 mins to figure out

Comment: for me the question is, which library is providing the function called "from_json" ? I cant seem to place that !!! Help please..

Comment: @Raghav -> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

check the example here: https://github.com/katsou55/kafka-spark-structured-streaming-example/blob/master/src/main/scala-2.11/Main.scala

Comment: @abaghel - I was referring your blog here - https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery&method=awaitTermination

without java bean, cant we parse/infer the json data ?

Comment: @abaghel i can't see the console output even though it print isStreaming as true