# Reading Kafka Connect JSONConverter messages with schema using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read message from Kafka Topic. Message are in below format (sample format):

`{"schema":{"type":"struct","name":"emp_table","fields":[{"field":"emp_id","type":"string"},{"field":"emp_name","type":"String"},{"field":"city","type":"string"},{"field":"emp_sal","type":"string"},{"field":"manager_name","type":"string"}]},"payload":{"emp_id":"1","emp_name":"abc","city":"NYK","emp_sal":"100000","manager_name":"xyz"}}`

Also, please note topic has message from different tables and not just 1 table.

What I am trying to achieve is to read above message from Kafka Topic using Spark Structured Streaming and create a dataframe with column names ad its value both coming from JSON message itself.

I don't want to explicitly define a schema using case class or StructType.

I tried this:

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers).option("subscribe", "topic1").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

val y=df.select(get_json_object(($"value"), "$.payload").alias("payload")
```

When I view Y (which is a dataframe), it comes as 1 column with value under payload as JSON in that column.

How to get individual column in a dataframe? I am not achieve this.

(Again reiterating I cannot use a generic case class or StructType for schema part as messages coming through Kafka message are from different tables so I want a more of dynamic Schema created from JSON itself on the run.)

Comment: Umh, you could probably access to single values via dot notation, payload.schema.type should return "struct" as value

Comment: I think you need to cast the value to a string (from a byte array) before you can use `get_json_object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Change the Kafka Connect source to set `value.converter.schemas.enable=false`. This will only give you the (unwrapped payload to begin with), then you can skip to below post.

Otherwise, after you strip the Connect schema, you would need to use `from_json()` to apply a schema

```
val y = df.select(get_json_object($"value", "$.payload").alias("payload"))
val z = df.select(from_json($"payload", schema))
```

All your fields are strings, so would look like

```
val schema: StructType = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("emp_id", StringType()),
  StructField("emp_name", StringType()),
  StructField("city", StringType()),
  StructField("emp_sal", StringType()),
  StructField("manager_name", StringType())
))
```

Related

- [How to use from_json with Kafka connect 0.10 and Spark Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506801/how-to-use-from-json-with-kafka-connect-0-10-and-spark-structured-streaming)
- https://github.com/katsou55/kafka-spark-structured-streaming-example/blob/master/src/main/scala-2.11/Main.scala
- [How to read records in JSON format from Kafka using Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297973/how-to-read-records-in-json-format-from-kafka-using-structured-streaming)

Comment: Hi @OneCriketeer, if my payload is like this 
```
"payload": {
    "data": {
      "nameField": "Myname",
      "AnotherField": [
        {
          "value": {
            "unitField": "MyUnit",
            "valueField": "27"
          }
        }
      ],
      "timestampField": "2020-08-01T18:00:00"
    }
  }
```
, would i need to define some kind of nested struct?

Comment: hmm. find something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57079343/spark-create-a-nested-schema

Comment: @Minnie `AnotherField` would need to be an Array type, yes

Comment: I am stuck and I will post my question below to keep the topic concentrated.

Comment: @Minnie Please create a new post rather than ask a question after an accepted answer

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63857217/4582240 . Sorry and thanks.