# Spark: create a nested schema

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, schema

With spark,

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = Seq(
  (1, ("value11", "value12")),
  (2, ("value21", "value22")),
  (3, ("value31", "value32"))
  )

 val df = data.toDF("id", "v1")
 df.printSchema()
```

The result is the following:

```
root
|-- id: integer (nullable = false)
|-- v1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Now if I want to create the schema myself, how should I process?

```
val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType),
  StructField("nested", ???)
))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to example in here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html

```scala
 import org.apache.spark.sql._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

 val innerStruct =
   StructType(
     StructField("f1", IntegerType, true) ::
     StructField("f2", LongType, false) ::
     StructField("f3", BooleanType, false) :: Nil)

 val struct = StructType(
   StructField("a", innerStruct, true) :: Nil)

 // Create a Row with the schema defined by struct
 val row = Row(Row(1, 2, true))
```

And in your case it will be:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("id", IntegerType),
  StructField("nested", StructType(Array(
      StructField("value1", StringType),
      StructField("value2", StringType)
  )))
))
```

Output:

```
StructType(
  StructField(id,IntegerType,true), 
  StructField(nested,StructType(
    StructField(value1,StringType,true), 
    StructField(value2,StringType,true)
  ),true)
)
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I expected. Now another question: from a flat dataframe, is it possible to get a nested one using .withColumn() to build the nested parts (and without using an RDD and the `Row(Row(1, 2, true))`)?