# Spark Structured Streaming to read nested Kafka Connect jsonConverter message

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have ingested xml file using KafkaConnect file-pulse connector 1.5.3
Then I want to read it with Spark Streaming to parse/flatten it. As it is quite nested.

**the string** I read out of the kafka (I used the consumer console read this out, and put an Enter/new line before the `payload` for illustration) is like below:

```
{
"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"city"},{"type":"array","items":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"array","items":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"unit"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"value"}],"optional":true,"name":"Value"},"optional":true,"field":"value"}],"optional":true,"name":"ForcedArrayType"},"optional":true,"field":"forcedArrayField"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"field":"lastField"}],"optional":true,"name":"Data","field":"data"}],"optional":true}

,"payload":{"data":{"city":"someCity","forcedArrayField":[{"value":[{"unit":"unitField1","value":"123"},{"unit":"unitField1","value":"456"}]}],"lastField":"2020-08-02T18:02:00"}}
}
```

**datatype** I attempted:

```
    StructType schema = new StructType();
    schema = schema.add( "schema", StringType, false);
    schema = schema.add( "payload", StringType, false);

    StructType Data = new StructType();
    StructType ValueArray = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("unit", StringType,true,Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("value", StringType,true,Metadata.empty())
    });
    StructType ForcedArrayType = new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField("valueArray", ValueArray,true,Metadata.empty())
    });

    Data = Data.add("city",StringType,true);
    Data = Data.add("forcedArrayField",ForcedArrayType,true);
    Data = Data.add("lastField",StringType,true);

    StructType Record = new StructType();
    Record = Record.add("data", Data, false);
```

**query** I attempted:

```
        //below worked for payload
        Dataset<Row> parsePayload = lines
                .selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")
                .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("json"), schema=schema).as("schemaAndPayload"))
                .select("schemaAndPayload.payload").as("payload");

        System.out.println(parsePayload.isStreaming());

        //below makes the output empty:
        Dataset<Row> parseValue = parsePayload.select(functions.from_json(functions.col("payload"), Record).as("cols"))
                .select(functions.col("cols.data.city"));
//.select(functions.col("cols.*"));

        StreamingQuery query = parseValue
                .writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .start();
        query.awaitTermination();
```

when I oupput the parsePayload stream, i could see the data(still json struture), but when i want to select certain/all field like above city. it is empty.

**help needed**
Is the cause  data type defined wrong? or the query is wrong?

Ps.
at the console, when i tried to output the 'parsePayload', instead of 'parseValue', it displays some data, which made me think the 'payload' part worked.

```
 |{"data":{"city":"...|
...
```

Comment: I have tried to understand here too : https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema definition seems to be not fully correct. I was replicating your problem and was able to parse the JSON with the following schema

```scala
val payloadSchema = new StructType()
  .add("data", new StructType()
    .add("city", StringType)
    .add("forcedArrayField", ArrayType(new StructType()
      .add("value", ArrayType(new StructType()
        .add("unit", StringType)
        .add("value", StringType)))))
    .add("lastField", StringType))
```

When I then access individual fields I used the following selection:

```scala
val parsePayload = df
    .selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json")
    .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("json"), schema).as("schemaAndPayload"))
    .select("schemaAndPayload.payload").as("payload")
    .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("payload"), payloadSchema).as("cols"))
    .select(col("cols.data.city").as("city"), explode(col("cols.data.forcedArrayField")).as("forcedArrayField"), col("cols.data.lastField").as("lastField"))
    .select(col("city"), explode(col("forcedArrayField.value").as("middleFields")), col("lastField"))
```

This gives the output

```
+--------+-----------------+-------------------+
|    city|              col|          lastField|
+--------+-----------------+-------------------+
|someCity|[unitField1, 123]|2020-08-02T18:02:00|
|someCity|[unitField1, 456]|2020-08-02T18:02:00|
+--------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @mike, I will give it a try. and let you know my test result.

Comment: It worked. The way I created the ArrayType was wrong, java syntax is 'crusty' to me, so I am glad you wrote it in scala. thanks @mike

Comment: sorry, i got confused by up arrow and accept as answer. I will try to remember that.

Comment: I wonder why the ```middleFields``` was not in the end result. instead it displays as 'col'. my next goal is to split this ```col/middleFields```,  into 2 cols and I did not want to  based on something is possible wrong.

Comment: actually i realized the middlefields was the alias for the exploded innner column, no problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a small problem with the paranthesis.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Schema Definition is wrong.
`payload` and `schema` might not be a column/field
Read it as a static Json ( Spark.read.json) and get the schema then use it in structured streaming.

Comment: This is not normal json  message. I was trying out  solution,See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56453971/4582240 the message schema part is ignored and I am trying to define my own schema for the payload part.