# Extracting "payload" from Kafka Connect JSONConverter messages with (schema & payload) using Spark Structured Streaming (pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

What I'm trying to accomplish is exactly what this question about ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034195/reading-kafka-connect-jsonconverter-messages-with-schema-using-spark-structured)) however; In my case I'm using Python/Pyspark Not Scala.

I'm trying to extract "payload" part of Kafka connect message that include schema as well.

Sample message :

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","name":"emp_table","fields":[{"field":"emp_id","type":"string"},{"field":"emp_name","type":"String"},{"field":"city","type":"string"},{"field":"emp_sal","type":"string"},{"field":"manager_name","type":"string"}]},"payload":{"emp_id":"1","emp_name":"abc","city":"NYK","emp_sal":"100000","manager_name":"xyz"}}
```

Step 1 - Defind schema for "payload" part:

```
payload_schema = StructType([
StructField("emp_id", StringType(), False),
StructField("emp_name", StringType(), True),
StructField("city", StringType(), True),
StructField("emp_sal", StringType(), True),
StructField("manager_name", StringType(), True)])
```

Step 2 - Read from Kafka :

```
df =spark.readStream.format("kafka")
```

Step 3 - get message value from Kafka message:

```
kafka_df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

Step 4 - Extract "payload" only (**I'm stuck here**):

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

    emp_df = kafka_df\
    .select(psf.from_json(psf.col('value'), payload_schema).alias("DF"))\
    .select("DF.*")
```

I'm stuck in this part as I couldn't figure out how to extract payload from JSON string before passing it to from_json() function.

**Note** : I'm aware of that I need to define the full schema for the entire message before I can make use of it in from_json(), however; I'm trying to get only "payload" json string part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the SQL function `get_json_object`:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

kafka_df
  .select(psf.get_json_object(kafka_df['value'],"$.payload").alias('payload'))
  .select(psf.from_json(psf.col('payload'), payload_schema).alias("DF"))
  .select("DF.*")
```

Or, you need to define the full schema for the entire message before you can make use of it in `from_json`.

That means your schema should rather look like below:

```py
full_schema = StructType([
  StructField("schema", StructType([
    StructField("type", StringType(), False),
    StructField("name", StringType(), False),
    StructField("fields", StructType([
      StructField("field", StringType(), False),
      StructField("type", StringType(), False)
    ]),
  StructField("payload", StructType([
    StructField("emp_id", StringType(), False),
    StructField("emp_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("city", StringType(), True),
    StructField("emp_sal", StringType(), True),
    StructField("manager_name", StringType(), True)
  ])
])
```

Please double check this schema definition as I am not entirely sure how to define an Array within a schema in Python, but I hope the idea is clear.

As soon as this is done, you can select the payload fields by

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

    emp_df = kafka_df\
    .select(psf.from_json(psf.col('value'), full_schema).alias("DF"))\
    .select("DF.payload.*")
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I'm aware of that I need to define the full schema for the entire message before I can make use of it in from_json(), however; I'm trying to avoid this and work only with payload part.

Comment: Okay, thank you for making this clear. It should work with the `get_json_object` function.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the hint. For some reason, I thought pyspark doesn't have get_json_object() function.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you don't have `schema` handy, you could do:

```
import json

df = kafka_df.select(psf.get_json_object(kafka_df.value, "$.payload").alias("payload"))
final_df = df.rdd.map(lambda row: json.loads(row[0])).toDF().show()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I missed that pyspark has get_json_object() function.
After Mike's comment I went back to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=udf) I found what I was looking for.

Here's the answer :

```
    kafka_df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    payload_df = kafka_df.select(psf.get_json_object(kafka_df.value, "$.payload").alias("payload"))
    emp_df = payload_df.select(psf.from_json(psf.col('payload'), schema).alias("DF")).select("DF.*")
```

Comment: Mike, I didn't copy your answer. I actually just saw your "updated" answer after I post my answer. I appreciate your help but I can assure that I'm mature enough and I wouldn't do such a thing and steal others effort.